# C++ Windows: Saving the line of an edit control into a vector of TCHAR

Tags: c++, windows, vector, sendmessage

The following code works fine:

```
int iLength = SendMessage(hWndEdit, EM_LINELENGTH, 0, 0);
if(iLength > 0) {
    TCHAR* szBuffer = new TCHAR[iLength+1];
    iLength = SendMessage(hWndEdit, EM_GETLINE, 0, (LPARAM)szBuffer);
    szBuffer[iLength] = TEXT('\0');
    MessageBox(hWnd, szBuffer, TEXT("Edit content"), MB_OK);
    delete[] szBuffer;
}
```

Now I want to do the same thing using `std::vector<TCHAR>`:

```
int iLength = SendMessage(hWndEdit, EM_LINELENGTH, 0, 0);
if(iLength > 0) {
    std::vector<TCHAR> data(iLength+1, TEXT('\0'));
    iLength = SendMessage(hWndEdit, EM_GETLINE, 0, (LPARAM)&data[0]);
    MessageBox(hWnd, &data[0], TEXT("Edit content"), MB_OK);
}
```

It compiles, but at `iLength = SendMessage(hWndEdit, EM_GETLINE, 0, (LPARAM)&data[0]);` the variable `iLength` will always be set to 0, and, accordingly, nothing will have been written into my vector.

What is the problem here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A pointer to the buffer that receives a copy of the line. **Before
>   sending the message, set the first word of this buffer to the size, in
>   `TCHAR`s, of the buffer**.

Comment: Thanks, though it costs me a line to push back the 0-termination of the string, this works fine!